« Ce qu'est » est-ce la contraction de « ce qui est » ou « ce que est » ?
Je vois « ce qu'est » souvent et le sens ne semble pas être différent de « ce qui est », ce que je vois aussi souvent. Pour moi, il semble que « ce qui est » est le bon usage parce que « qui » dénote le sujet du verbe « est (être) » et « ce que est » traite le « ce » comme l'objet de « être », qui ne prend pas d'objet.
Est-ce simplement la contraction de « ce qui est », ou bien « ce que est » existe en vrai ? Si oui, est-ce le bon usage ?

Il serait mieux de donner des exemples avec des phrases.

J'aurais aimé les fournir mais malheureusement je ne peux pas me rappeler où exactement ai-je vu ces phrases, mais j'en suis sûr que je les ai vu plusieurs fois.

"ce qui est" n'a pas de contraction.

@Lambie À l'oral, il y en au moins trois et à l'écrit, tout dépend du registre. On peut certainement rencontrer deux élisions dans ce qui est.

@Lambie De quoi parles-tu ? Il n'est pas question de qu'il ici. Qu'appelles-tu contraction qui n'existerait pas avec ce qui est ?

Le pronom relatif 'qui' ne s'élide jamais  Ce qui est rare est cher. https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-54800.php Comme None a remarqué...

Que (qu') peut avoir la fonction grammaticale d'attribut (du sujet). C'est le cas dans ce qu'est.

Pour trouver une phrase où qu' serait mis pour qui dans l'expression ce qu'est il faudrait qu'on puisse élider la lettre i finale du pronom relatif. Or il me semble à priori que ce n'est pas possible, à l'écrit. Comme l'indique @jlliagre en commentaire en parlant (donc uniquement à l'oral) de façon très relâchée le i peut disparaitre.

J'ai compris ce qu'est la souffrance en travaillant à l'hôpital.
Il sait ce qu'est l'adversité.
Il faut développer les campagnes d’information pour faire comprendre ce qu’est une discrimination.

Dans ces phrases qu' est attribut du sujet. (souffrance, adversité, discrimination).
Pour se convaincre que c'est bien que et pas qui, mettons le sujet du verbe être au pluriel, ce qui va empêcher l'élision de la voyelle finale du pronom relatif puisqu'elle se trouvera devant une consonne.

J'ai compris ce que sont les souffrances des malades.
Il faut développer les campagnes d’information pour faire comprendre ce que sont les discriminations.


Merci pour l'explication. Mais est-il incorrect d'utiliser "ce qui" ici ? Peux-je dire "J'ai compris ce qui sont les souffrances des malades." ? Je crois que au moins, je peux dire "J'ai compris ces chose, qui sont les souffrances des malades," non ? Si la dernière est bonne, on remplace "ces choses" avec "ce", alors maintenant on obtiens la première phrase encore.

Dans les phrases que je donne en exemple on ne pourrait pas mettre "ce qui". On dirait plutôt J'ai compris ces choses que sont les souffrances des malades. "*J'ai compris ce que sont les souffrances des malades."  Autre chose: Puis-je dire...

Or il me semble à priori que ce n'est pas possible. +1 https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-54800.php

@None Ce n'est pas possible quand on s'en tient à l'écrit académique mais l'élision se rencontre à l'oral relâché, et dans un registre courant, on a aussi une fusion de qui et de est. L'expression ce qui est peut donc avoir trois, deux ou une seule syllabe : /sə.ki.ɛ/, /ski.ɛ/, /sə.kjɛ/, /skjɛ/ ainsi que le fustigé /skɛ/. ex: Enfin c'est c'qu'est dit sur le papelard...

@jlliagre Mais qui donc a decidé que la question porte sur "l'orale relâché" ? Cela semble être une question à part. C'est comme gonna et wanna en anglais. –

@Lambie Le français parlé n'est assurément plus ton dada, c'est ton droit mais de toute façon, gonna et wanna auraient certainement leur place si quelqu'un posait une question sur les contractions de going to and want to sur ELL.

@jlliagre Ta remarque est très juste (ajoutée dans la réponse histoire de faire le tour de la question), bien sûr, mais la question disant Je vois souvent il est difficile de comprendre qu'elle porterait sur l'oral. Mais d'accord il est bon de  préciser ce qui pourrait se passer à l'oral.

@jlliagre Tu sais que dalle sur "ce qui est" mon dada. "gonna et wanna auraient certainement leur place si quelqu'un posait une question sur les contractions de going to and want to sur ELL." Bien sûr, mais ici ce n'était pas le cas.

@Lambie Ah, là je suis d'accord avec toi. Cette question ne porte pas ici sur les contractions de going to et want to. Elle porte cependant sur les contractions de ce que est et ce qui est, ce qui t'a peut-être échappé.

Merci, maintenant je vois d'où vient ma confusion. Je pensais que le verbe "être" peut avoir le pronom subjectif aux deux côté comme anglais (It is I) ou allemand (Das bin ich), mais en français il faut utiliser le pronom objectif. Si c'était de forme "ce que font les gens" (un verbe à part être) j'aurais aucune confusion comme je sais déjà que "faire" exige un objet

@jlliagre Why don't you stop making personal comments?

@Lambie Why don't you stop making pointless and arrogant comments?
